# what is the 'transform' vector that appear in xcode console when printing object?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode

I'm inspecting a UIView after rotation.
So while debugging, i go to console and type

```
print-object [self view]
```

and i get

```
<UIView: 0x4b14e40; frame = (0 0; 748 1024); transform = [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x4b16ea0>>
```

so i noticed the 'transform' vector. But i couldn't find what does it mean. and if it's related to the orientation changes and rotation taking place.And if so, what does represent each number? it seems like a translation matrix but 6 variables? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that your view suffered a transformation, like rotation, translations, scale.
For more information see the method

```
CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformMake(CGFloat a, CGFloat b, CGFloat c, CGFloat d, CGFloat tx, CGFloat ty)
```